# Selenium wait until element is not present

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, timeout

I am doing an upload with Selenium, after the upload an elements gets invisible and I know its completed. The problem is this code throws a WebDriverException  everytime after 1 minute and I don't know why since I set the timeout to 5 minutes.

It would be great if someone knows a solution for this. Thank you :)

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath(xpath)));
```

Comment: Have you used implicit wait also? I mean make sure you are not mixing implicit and explicit waits.

Comment: What exception it throws?

Comment: Thanks both of you and sorry for the late reply.
I removed all other implicit and explicit waits I had before this code, but the error still occurs .__.

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7056/hub/session/3e607979-bca7-4834-8db2-ba6e2a871637/element timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: Timeout für Vorgang überschritten